# Is the marginal distribution of $X$ the value of $X$ at a single point or its entire distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, definition

I am confused whether the marginal distribution of a variable refers to its entire distribution  or only the probability of a certain value which it assumes. My textbook has the following definition for a marginal distribution:

> When given a joint distribution for $X$ and $Y$, the distribution $\mathbb{P}[X=a]$ for $X$ is called the marginal distribution for $X$, and can be found by "summing" over the values of $Y$. That is,
> $$
> \mathbb{P}[X=a]=\sum_{b \in \mathscr{B}} \mathbb{P}[X=a, Y=b]
> $$ where $\mathscr{B}$ is
> the set of all possible values taken by $Y$.

Here, it seems we only get the probability of a single value which $X$ assumes, $a$. However, my textbook also claims that

> The marginal distribution for $X_i$
> is simply the distribution for $X_i$ and can be obtained by summing over all
> the possible values of the other variables.

This makes me think that the marginal distribution is the entire distribution of a variable, not only at a single point. So which of these views is correct, and how am I misinterpreting the information I am given?

Comment: *(Saying "the distribution $\mathbb{P}[X=a]$" presupposes $X$ has a discrete distribution with a probability mass function, but that might be dealt with by talking about the cumulative distribution function $\mathbb{P}[X\le a]$; you can generalise this further to a probability measure.)*  The essential point here is that you are talking about a function, and the distribution is determined by this function's values on the support of the random variable $X$, i.e. for all relevant $a$ rather than just  for an individual value of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doubts are justified. The different values of $a$ are missing in the definition of the marginal distribution. The right definition would be

$$
\mathbb{P}[X=a]=\begin{cases}\sum_{b \in \mathscr{B}} \mathbb{P}[X=a, Y=b] \quad
\color{blue}{\forall \ \  a \in\mathscr{A}}  \\ 0, \textrm{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$ where $\mathscr{A}$,$\mathscr{B}$ are
the sets of all possible values taken by $X,Y$, respectively. The blue part considers all possible values of $a$. Thus you receive the pmf of $X$.